# (MACOSX) - Knowing whether a mounted device was mounted from a DMG

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

Couldn't find that info using DiskArbitration or FSGetVolumeInfo/GetVolumeParms...

I know that hdiutil uses a private framework called DiskImages framework, but I wouldn't want to run an external utility each time I want this info... wheres the API for this ?

Answer (score 1):

**July 2015 Update**

*This update was prompted by Stan James' [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545381/determine-if-a-volume-is-a-disk-image-dmg-from-code).*

You can obtain this information using the [DiskArbitration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Conceptual/DiskArbitrationProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework. To use the example below, you must link against and `#import` it.

```
#import <DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration.h>
```

...

```
- (BOOL)isDMGVolumeAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{

  BOOL isDMG = NO;

  if (url.isFileURL) {

    DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    if (session != nil) {

      DADiskRef disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, (__bridge CFURLRef)url);
      if (disk != nil) {

        NSDictionary * desc = CFBridgingRelease(DADiskCopyDescription(disk));
        NSString * model = desc[(NSString *)kDADiskDescriptionDeviceModelKey];
        isDMG = ([model isEqualToString:@"Disk Image"]);

        CFRelease(disk);

      }

      CFRelease(session);

    }

  }

  return isDMG;

}
```

Usage:

```
BOOL isDMG = [someObject isDMGVolumeAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Volumes/Some Volume"]];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sure it does. The code to which I linked detects the very situation you described (even if it's intended for a different purpose) so it can offer to move/copy the app into the Applications folder. Therefore, it's reasonable to expect to find the answer to your question in this example, no?

Comment: That link no longer works, but I tracked down the relevant code and added it to my similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545381/determine-if-a-volume-is-a-disk-image-dmg-from-code

Comment: I've updated my answer here based on the answer to Stan James' question.