# Determine if a Volume is a Disk Image (DMG) from code

Tags: objective-c, macos, filesystems, nsurl, diskimage

From Objective C (or Swift), I need to determine if a mounted volume is a Disk Image (mounted from a .dmg file).

Similar questions led me to [NSURL Volume Property Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Volume_Property_Keys), but none of them seem to give the type/protocol of the volume.

However, I can see this information with the terminal `diskutil` function under `Protocol`:

```
~/Temp$ diskutil info /dev/disk8
   Device Identifier:        disk8
   Device Node:              /dev/disk8
   Part of Whole:            disk8
   Device / Media Name:      Apple UDIF read-only Media

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image <=== THIS IS WHAT I WANT
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               5.2 MB (5242880 Bytes) (exactly 10240 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          Yes
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

EDIT: Found [some code](https://github.com/PuppyBongos/standing-desk-app/blob/master/M3InstallController.m#L53) that at least used to do this, by means of [this included category extension to NSWorkspace](https://github.com/jeffchao/hedgewars-accessible/blob/master/QTfrontend/NSWorkspace_RBAdditions.m). However, it is pre-ARC and I'm not sure if it would still work.

Found it via [this partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2622521/59913) on other question..

Comment: I did not try it, but what about NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey, perhaps in combination with NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey ? Just an idea.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! However, I think this would also catch removable HD and SSD drives, which are the drives I *want* to detect.  (And right now I'm getting false positives on every dmg installer that I open.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can obtain this information using the [DiskArbitration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Conceptual/DiskArbitrationProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework. To use the example below, you must link against and `#import` it.

```
#import <DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration.h>
```

...

```
- (BOOL)isDMGVolumeAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{

  BOOL isDMG = NO;

  if (url.isFileURL) {

    DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    if (session != nil) {

      DADiskRef disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, (__bridge CFURLRef)url);
      if (disk != nil) {

        NSDictionary * desc = CFBridgingRelease(DADiskCopyDescription(disk));
        NSString * model = desc[(NSString *)kDADiskDescriptionDeviceModelKey];
        isDMG = ([model isEqualToString:@"Disk Image"]);

        CFRelease(disk);

      }

      CFRelease(session);

    }

  }

  return isDMG;

}
```

Usage:

```
BOOL isDMG = [someObject isDMGVolumeAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Volumes/Some Volume"]];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Amazing. The most perfect answer one could hope for on SO: a working function, the needed #import, and an example call. It's up and running in my project now.